# Weird behavior of the != XPath operator

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements

I'm attempting to create an xsl:choose statement with multiple conditions to test.  So far, I have this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$AccountNumber != '12345' and $Balance != '0'">
       <do stuff here>
       ...
```

The problem is that the 'and' is being treated as an 'or'.  If the account number is 12345 or the balance of an account is 0, the condition is treated as true and the  code gets executed.  I need the test to be that both conditions must be true... do I have the syntax wrong here?

Thanks in advance,
~Tim

Comment: I hope [this page](http://www.java2s.com/Code/XML/XSLT-stylesheet/ifstatementwithandoperator.htm) gonna help

Comment: What do the variables $AccountNumber and $Balance contain exactly? Empty node sets, for example, can lead to surprising results because `$empty-node-set != '0'` will be false.

Comment: How are $AccountNumber and $Balance defined? Please show us that.

Answer (score 44):

> The problem is that the 'and' is being treated as an 'or'.

No, the problem is that you are using the XPath `!=` operator and you aren't aware of its "weird" semantics.

**Solution**:

Just replace the any `x != y` expressions with a `not(x = y)` expression.

**In your specific case**:

**Replace**:

```
<xsl:when test="$AccountNumber != '12345' and $Balance != '0'">
```

**with**:

```
<xsl:when test="not($AccountNumber = '12345') and not($Balance = '0')">
```

**Explanation**:

By definition whenever one of the operands of the `!=` operator is a nodeset, then the result of evaluating this operator is true if there is a node in the node-set, whose value isn't equal to the other operand.

**So**:

```
 $someNodeSet != $someValue
```

generally doesn't produce the same result as:

```
 not($someNodeSet = $someValue)
```

The latter (by definition) is true exactly when there isn't a node in `$someNodeSet` whose string value is equal to `$someValue`.

**Lesson to learn**:

Never use the `!=` operator, unless you are absolutely sure you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 8):

If `$AccountNumber` or `$Balance` is a node-set, then this behavior could easily happen.  It's not because `and` is being treated as `or`.

For example, if `$AccountNumber` referred to nodes with the values `12345` and `66` and `$Balance` referred to nodes with the values `55` and `0`, then
`$AccountNumber != '12345'` would be true (because `66` is not equal to `12345`) and `$Balance != '0'` would be true (because `55` is not equal to `0`).

I'd suggest trying this instead:

```
<xsl:when test="not($AccountNumber = '12345' or $Balance = '0')">
```

`$AccountNumber = '12345' or $Balance = '0'` will be true any time there is an `$AccountNumber` with the value `12345` or there is a `$Balance` with the value `0`, and if you apply `not()` to that, you will get a false result.

Comment: Nice use of De Morgan's Laws.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used this syntax, which yields more predictable results than using !=.

```
<xsl:when test="not($AccountNumber = '12345') and not($Balance = '0')" />
```

Comment: Both forms are equally "predictable" if you appreciate exactly what they are defined to mean.  If `$AccountNumber` is a node set containing more than one node then `$AccountNumber != '12345'` and `not($AccountNumber = '12345')` mean _fundamentally_ different things - the former is true if there is _any_ node in the set with a value different from 12345, the latter only if _none_ of the nodes in the set has value 12345.